# List running processes on 64-bit Windows

Tags: python, windows, process

I amm writing a little python script that will grab information from VMs of Windows that I am running.

At the moment I can list the processes on a 32bit XP machine with the following method:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305279/

Is it possible to somehow detect the version of windows running and excute a different method for getting the processes on a 64bit machine, I am trying to get the processes from a 64Bit Vista and 64bit Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is another recipe on activestate that does a similar thing, but uses the Performance Data Helper library (PDH) instead.

I have tested this on my Windows 7 64bit machine and it works there - so presumably the same function will work on both 32bit and 64 bit windows.

You can find the recipe here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303339/

Another method is using WMI, there is an example here in Python using the [wmi](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) module:

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

Comment: Does WMI work on 64bit windows also?  I can not see anything on there site that mentions 64bit, or do you use the same method names?

Comment: It should work the same way (including method) names for both environments.

Comment: I have been utilizing this method in my application, but we are noticing significant CPU spikes when this lookup gets triggered.  I originally thought it was the scheduler I am using, but I started commenting out code until I got down to this specific code.  Commented out, no significant spikes.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I should add the approach Jonathan Rocher posted doesn't have this issue and has the benefit of being platform agnostic.

Comment: `pip install wmi` seem to succeed and mirror the release on the linked website.

Comment: If you get an module not found error similar to "module win32something not found" or similar,  install the right release of [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) from there.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to rely on any extra installed modules then you can parse the output of [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx), e.g.:

```
c:\> wmic process get description,executablepath    
...
explorer.exe               C:\Windows\explorer.exe
cmd.exe                    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
conhost.exe                C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe
...
```

Reference: http://geekpedia.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/use-command-line-to-track-windows-processes/

Answer (score 11):

The cleanest way I found to solve this was to use the [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/index.html) library as recommended by Robert Lujo:

```
psutil.process_iter()
```

Note that it returns a generator object, issuing a process object at a time. For example if you need the list of process names, you can do something like:

```
[p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()]
```

Comment: hi, that one's nice, just a question, as p is a process with pid and name, why do you get p.name() with brackets ? and why doesn't it work if I want to get the pids ? I'm trying to get the matching pid/name

Answer (score 9):

For similar purposes I have used [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) library. Some hints:

- list processes with `psutil.pids()` ([reference](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.pids))
- inspect process information with `process = psutil.Process(pid)` ([reference](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#process-class))
- do `process.kill` or `process.terminate()`

[Installation](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) on windows - `pip` will do installation from the source (which means compiling), so you probably want to download binary installation from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/#downloads.

Comment: psutil limits its output of processes to the current user running the python script. Hence a non-admin user will not see privileged processes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by exposing [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) within each VM. This tool gives you access to a bunch of system data, including processes, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757287%28WS.10%29.aspx

You should be able to `popen` one of the commands in the preceding link to get the info you're looking for.

Comment: It is significantly better to use a tool like win32process or psutils than it is to pipe output from a command line command. Something that is intentionally integrated with python will always be easier and cleaner to use.