# How to find process ids of running applications using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's suppose 3 applications are open on windows 7.

**First,**

- I want to print the process ids of the running applications.

**Second**,

- I want to kill the selected application.

How can this be done using python.

The purpose is to make an application which kills the selected process.

Comment: what are the windows?

Comment: simply, "close window" means kill the process

Comment: I think you will need to edit your question and be a bit more specific on what you are trying to do. Are you using a unix or windows system?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I edit the question. can you understand?

Comment: This seems a duplicate (pretty much) of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find all the `chrome` pids and kill  them, it is cross platform:

```
import psutil
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name == "chrome":
        print (p.pid)
        p.kill()
```

There are lots of examples [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil#downloads)

Comment: Is there any Idea to choose process which is on task bar?

Comment: have a look at the link in my answer.

Comment: p.name does not return process's name. p.name() == "chrome" is right.