# How do I get python to fetch information from command prompt such as 'tasklist'

Tags: python, command, windows-8.1

I want a program in python that can get a list of all of the programs running, like all the .exe's, and I want to be able to get them into a variable or array so that I can maybe use a for loop to go through them and filter ones to be shut-down, this is what I've got below to try and get the tasklist using the tasklist command in python, any ideas on how to get all of the task names that the command prompt gives me into an array or variable

```
    import os 
    def shut():
        return(os.system('tasklist'))
    print(shut())
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: well that gave me an answer, thanks

Comment: or not, im running python 3.4.2 and that thread uses outdated python and xp 32 bit  not windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: The example there (using the `wmi` library) works for me on Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/tasklist.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wmi
ImportError: No module named 'wmi'

Comment: `wmi` is an external library, you need to install by executing `pip install wmi`  in the cmd or via your IDE if you're using Pycharm.

Comment: i need a solution that will work without external librarys if possible because the document will have to be ran on a system that isnt mine where i cant get external librarys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the check_output function:

```py
from subprocess import check_output
var = check_output('tasklist')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using Python 3 and `tasklist`:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('tasklist', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, error) = proc.communicate()

if error is not None:
    print("error:", error.decode())

print("output:", output.decode())
```

The `decode`s are required because byte objects are returned.