# How to tell if windows processes have started

Tags: python, windows

I wrote a program called load, to show a loading bar for 0:45 seconds while another program is starting which has no indication that it is loading. It works exactly as I want when the system is already running, but I have it so it runs at startup which causes the program to take a 1:45 to start. I am trying to figure out a way to check if it is a fresh system start. I don't have any code yet since I don't know where to start. The only solutions I've thought of are just making a load1 and load2 where load1 has a loading bar of 1:45 that is run at startup and load2 is 0:45. My other idea is trying to schedule a task if that is possible. The only problem with that is that it would display nothing for 1:00 which kind of defeats the purpose. I don't really like either of these solutions.

Another possibility that would work is if I can check if I am calling it from the desktop or the startup folder. I'm having no luck with that though.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can possible get some help from this thread; [List running processes on 64-bit Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows).

Comment: @Robin I'm not sure that is going to be enough.  I need to tell when all the processes have fully started up rather than if they've started. Assuming I am understanding that recipe correctly then that will only be able to tell me if the processes started.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`WaitForInputIdle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with uses two batch files. One to run Load with an argument of 105 that is in the startup folder and the other batch file will be put on the desktop with a time of 45. Not my favorite solution, but it gets the job done and it's fairly easy to understand.