# Checking if program is running programmatically

Tags: python, windows, process

I was wondering how you could check if program is running using python and if not run it. I have two python scripts one is GUI which monitors another script.So basically if second script for some reason crashes I would like it start over.

n.b. I'm using `python 3.4.2` on Windows.

Comment: Google around and see what pidfile is, maybe that will solve your problem.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: `sudo apt-get install supervisor`

Comment: supervisor isn't right here, I need windows management adn supervisor is unix like

Comment: http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/python/check_script_not_already_running

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The module psutil can help you. To list all process runing use:

```
import psutil

print(psutil.pids()) # Print all pids
```

To access the process information, use:

```
p = psutil.Process(1245)  # The pid of desired process
print(p.name()) # If the name is "python.exe" is called by python
print(p.cmdline()) # Is the command line this process has been called with
```

If you use `psutil.pids()` on a for, you can verify all if this process uses python, like:

```
for pid in psutil.pids():
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    if p.name() == "python.exe":
        print("Called By Python:"+ str(p.cmdline())
```

The documentation of psutil is available on: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

## EDIT 1

Supposing if the name of script is Pinger.py, you can use this function

```
def verification():
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        if p.name() == "python.exe" and len(p.cmdline()) > 1 and "Pinger.py" in p.cmdline()[1]:
            print ("running")
```

Comment: I think it's not one of default python libs, or I'm wrong? if so i found this lib https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil , do you this this one is right?

Comment: Yes, you right, this lib is not a default lib, but you link is correct, is the same module

Comment: Another question, I see this reacts in all python scripts As python.exe, but I would like to check seperate script not the main which has psutil

Comment: the p.cmdline() line returns a list like ["python.exe", "your_script.py"], using this you can check the second position in the list.

Comment: p.cmdline()[1] gets me 3 running programs : running.py ; Pinger.Py ; running.py; and it does't return true as it should

Comment: so i just edited it to   if len(p.cmdline()) > 1 and  "Pinger.py" in p.cmdline()[1]:
   print ("running")

Comment: Okay, it's changed =)