# How to interact with open Rhino3D application using Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, rhino3d

I am currently opening Rhino and running Rhino command lines using `subprocess.call()` in an external python script.

```py
rhinoPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Rhinoceros 5\\System\\Rhino4.exe"
rhinoCommandFilePath = "Z:\\Arkangus\\2019\\RhinoCommand.txt"
scriptCall = "_-ReadCommandFile {0}".format(rhinoCommandFilePath)
callScript = '"{0}" /nosplash /runscript="{1}" /runscript="_-Exit"'.format(rhinoPath, scriptCall)
subprocess.call(callScript)
```

However, it means opening Rhino everytime I am running the script, and closing it after.

**Is there a way to check if Rhino is already open and run the RhinoCommand file directly into Rhino if it is the case?**

I am not looking for a pipe between Rhino and Python.

Thank you!

Comment: have you looked here https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/?

Comment: Yes, but if I'm correct rhinopython is to be used within rhino. I was probably not clear enough, I want to run the python script externally from Rhino.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/mcneel/rhino.inside/tree/master/CPython? It might help.

Comment: I had not, thanks for the link! I will take a look. I found compute_rhino3d and rhino3dm meanwhile though, will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To check if Rhino is already open (Note: this is only a *partial* answer to my issue):

[Checking if program is running programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37678954/11225613)

```
import psutil

def is_rhino_open():
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        if p.name() == "Rhino5.exe":
            print ("Rhino5 is running!")
```

Other way: use Rhino's compute functions directly from within Python (no need to open Rhino) with the CPython3.x modules `rhino3dm` and `compute_rhino3d`.

https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/run-script-from-windows-command-prompt-with-open-rhino/80736/2?u=gabriel.taquet