# Is there a way to check if a specific process is running using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a straightforward code where a variable = 0 if Instagram isn't running and = 1 if it is but I can't find a tool that can do this for me. I am relatively new to Python programming so most answers to similar questions that I've seen on this were confusing.

In short, is there a way to detect if an app/process such as Instagram is open on my computer?

[image: How can I detect this using Python]

Comment: Do you have anything? Have you done any research?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the following: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787120/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1632234/11301900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check by process name, iterating on all processes

```
import psutil

def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;
```

More intersting examples can be found [here](https://thispointer.com/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-by-name-and-find-its-process-id-pid/)

Comment: Why the semicolon and nonstandard names? Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Processes on UNIX based systems create a lock file to notify that a program is running, so `os.stat(location_of_file)` can be checked. If the file exists, the program is running, otherwise not.

Other than this, `psutil` works really fine in these kind of problems.

```
import psutil
b = psutils.pid_exists(pid)
if b:
   print ('Running')
```

This can be further checked at http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.pid_exists

```
for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
    if "instagram.exe" in (p.info['name']).lower():
        print ('Running')
```

On Windows, `FindWindow` can also be used.

```
import win32ui
if FindWindow ("Instagram", "Instagram"):
   print ('Running')
```