# ps aux | grep foo equivalent in windows without truncating the command in the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, batch-file

I am currently converting a few shell files to python inorder to add the same functionality to windows.
I am restricted to using python and batch commands and not powershell since this is a part of a bigger program that only uses those two.

So i am searching for a batch equivalent to the bash command `ps aux | grep foo | grep -v grep`.

I have tried `tasklist /v | findstr foo` .

This seems to work but the reason for printing this is to see all the process that are currently running and the tasklist command truncates the commnd after a few parameters.

Ex. If the op of ps aux | grep foo | grep -v grep is as follows :

`root 1599162  0.0  0.0   9040  2500 pts/20   <doesnt matter>   03:47   0:00 foo <param1> <param2> <param3> ....` **`<last param passed to foo>` **

The tasklist /v | findstr foo gives the following output in windows:

`foo.exe                  7624 RDP-Tcp#1                  2     10,852 K Unknown         <user loginID>                          0:00:00 foo.exe <param1> <param2> <param3>`

(The parameters post 3rd or 4th until the last are not printed. Those are the important ones needed to differentiate the running commands from each other).

#1 How do we get the complete untruncated command that is currently running?
Also #2 Does tasklist list the processes running on a different command prompt.

Comment: use powershell and command `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Select-Object CommandLine`.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid powershell as the entire structure was in batch/python modules. But i guess i will have to incorporate powershell.  I am using the following command though for more details. `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Select-Object Name, ProcessId, CreationDate, CommandLine | findstr foo`

Comment: Not sure why you want to use an external command when you already have Python. `wmi` can be directly queried from within Python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-list-of-running-processes/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/1632234/150978

Comment: What do you mean `tasklist` truncates?

Comment: @Squashman What i meant was as i mentioned in the question, Although the exe name is obtained, if we wish to see the entire command that is running along with its parameters i am not able to do that using tasklist

Answer (score 0):

Following Robert's comment about wmi , explored the wmic and python wmi module.
Although deprecated, wmic works for me and i found is right fit to relace in place of the

```
ps aux | grep foo | grep -v grep
```

.
Replaced the above command with the following:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe" process get Name,ProcessId,CommandLine,CreationDate /FORMAT:TABLE | C:\Windows\System32\findstr "foo CommandLine" | C:\Windows\System32\findstr /V "wmic findstr cmd.exe python"
```

The last findtsr /V was added as there were additional results also showing up which were to be eliminated.
The result was similar to the following:

```
CommandLine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           CreationDate               Name                         ProcessId
foo <params-list>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             20240215010001.243056-480  foo.exe                   4972
foo <params-list>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             20240215010004.237062-480  foo.exe                   7424
foo <params-list>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             20240215010007.237142-480  foo.exe                   7084
foo <params-list>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             20240215010010.237401-480  foo.exe                   9016
```

Although the spacing is a little off than what i would like, there are a lot of extra spaces after the commandLine

Comment: Knowing that wmic.exe is deprecated and will be removed from Windows in the future, why didn't you go the python module route?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to format as CSV?

Comment: @squashman Yes the python module would have been better, but that needed slightly more understanding. I dint have to go into the python module intricacies and it works for now. Regarding the csv format-I need to print it on the terminal...So i guess the table should be fine.